# Convert double index to matrix PANDAS

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with double index. Each index is represents an edge. I would like to pivot(?) it into matrix. First index should become columns and second index should remain index.

What path should I choose?

Comment: For the record, a short data sample and expected output helps us understand to know what you're really asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "double index" I assume you mean a ["hierarchical index" (aka MultiIndex)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex). If so,
you could use the [`unstack` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking):

```
In [160]: df
Out[160]: 
0  0     0
   1     1
   2     2
   3     3
1  0     4
   1     5
   2     6
   3     7
2  0     8
   1     9
   2    10
   3    11
dtype: int32

In [161]: df.unstack(level=0)
Out[161]: 
   0  1   2
0  0  4   8
1  1  5   9
2  2  6  10
3  3  7  11
```